# What happens when both arguments have different length of lists in a Python map function?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

```
list(map(lambda x, y: x+y, [1,2,3], [1,2,3,4]))
```

If the lengths of two lists differ, does the program evaluate until one of them finishes its iteration? So for the example above, it would be [2, 4, 6].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the shortest input argument is used to set the bounds on the length of the input. [According to the docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

> Return an iterator that applies function to every item of iterable, yielding the results. If additional iterable arguments are passed, function must take that many arguments and is applied to the items from all iterables in parallel. **With multiple iterables, the iterator stops when the shortest iterable is exhausted.**

---

Worth noting: this is different from the Python 2.x behavior, which evaluates using the longest list and extending the shorter list(s) with `None` as needed.

Comment: +1 for noting that Python 2.x evaluates using the longer list. (Specifically, NoneType is used as filler once the shorter list has completed.)

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.3 reference:

**map(function, iterable, ...)**: Return an iterator that applies function to every item of iterable, yielding the results. If additional iterable arguments are passed, function must take that many arguments and is applied to the items from all iterables in parallel. ***With multiple iterables, the iterator stops when the shortest iterable is exhausted.***